# Software Centre - where did my "Other" items come from?

Tags: software-center

In the Software Centre, under Installed Software, I have a number of packages marked as coming form "other". Where might these have come from? The `libdvdcss2` entry does not surprise me, but I have no idea where the qt and update-manager entries have come from.

As far as I'm aware I have never installed these packages from a PPA, or installed them manually.

Update: After taking the screenshot I removed the qt packages because I don't actually need them. However the output of `$ apt-cache policy update-manager` is:

```
update-manager:
  Installed: 1:0.142.21
  Candidate: 1:0.142.21
  Version table:
 *** 1:0.142.21 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:0.142.20 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main i386 Packages
     1:0.142.19 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main i386 Packages
```

I'm wondering if it could be to do with the maverick-proposed repository.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: Interesting question, and yeah, I see that too...  :)

Comment: @Janc Do you have the proposed repositories enabled?

Comment: Yes, but somehow things like `libqt4-dbus` and `update-manager` aren't in -proposed.  Maybe they got removed because of a problem?

Comment: I think you're right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version which is currently installed is no longer available on any of the configured repositories.
Do you have the -proposed repository enabled ? I believe there were some recent uploads to update-manager there which were rolled back, that would explain it...

About to the main part of the question, Software Center is only able to determine the "Origin" of a package if it is still available from an active repository, when the Origin is unknown it's shown on the "Other" item.

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal run:

```
apt-cache policy libqt4-dbus
```

If the repository from which you got the packages is still enabled you will see it on the list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I updated my question, please can you take a look.